# TableView Controller in Collection View Cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Problem: I want the user to be able to slide through various tableviews, that will appear in collection view cells. But these tableviews require their own controllers since they will be dynamically sized with different prototype cells. How does one go about doing this in swift 2?

My Failed Approach: Make a storyboard with the tableview controller set up as a scene and then try to instatiate it in code as the collection view cell. I am making the collection view programmatically.

Comment: Have you thinking about a horizontal scroll View with adjacent container views, every one having a UITableViewController?

Comment: So I'm using a collection view flow layout which is essentially a horizontal scroll view between collection view cells. My question is how to I place a UITableViewController in a collection view cell? Would making a container in each collection view cell make sense?